# Completely delete a folder in Windows using command line

Tags: windows, command-line

I need to delete one folder containing other folders and files inside. I tried `del` and `rmdir` commands but sometimes they fail with some error lines: `[PATH]: The directory isn't empty.`

Is there any good alternative?

Comment: I've experienced inconsistency in whether rmdir with appropriate flags removes everything in a directory tree (and/or the tree itself), and the only possible explanation I have is what Harry Johnston says.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This happens to me a lot with my automated build scripts.

I guess the reason might be some application that has a file open in that directory with "share delete". I.e. the application allows a deletion of the file (which is why I figure the DeleteFile call doesn't fail), but the file will only disappear after said application has closed it's handle.

That means the file might still be there when the `rmdir` command tries to delete the folder, hence the error message. Soon after that, said application will close it's handle, the file will disappear, and when you inspect the folder to see which file `rmdir` was talking about it will be empty.

At least that's my theory.

The workaround proposed by Harry Johnston looks good. Only I would insert a pause in between the `rmdir` commands. Of course Windows has no easily scriptable "pause" command (correction: ancient Windows versions don't, newer have - see comments). But if seconds granularity is enough one can use `ping` to create a pause:

```
ping -n {desired_delay_in_seconds + 1} 127.0.0.1 >nul
```

So in total:

```
rd /s /q foo
:: retry once
if exist foo (
    :: clear errorlevel
    cmd /c
    :: pause
    ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul
    :: retry
    rd /s /q foo
)
:: retry yet again
if exist foo (
    cmd /c
    ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul
    rd /s /q foo
)
:: give up
if exist foo {panic}
```

Comment: In my experience, a pause is never necessary, but YMMV.  (Of course if there really is another application in play it is preferable to identify it and explicitly wait for it to exit if possible.)

Comment: Well... I implemented a 10x retry-loop with one second delay per retry. Works now. I'm not going to try to remove the pause, only to see it fail again :-)
Of course that doesn't mean it's necessary. Just being extra-cautious.

Comment: OT: This is why I hate windows. Everything is so hard. `rm -rf /directory/` should be global on all operating systems.

Comment: There is actually a "pause" command of sorts; to pause three seconds you can use this: `timeout /t 3`

Comment: @r_alex_hall Indeed (but natively only from Vista onwards, XP and earlier don't have the `pause` command).

Comment: Yes, maybe I should have mentioned that. I often have to work with very old Windows versions which causes me to forget stuff that's only available on "newer" systems. And BTW: `pause` != `timeout` ;) `pause` (the "press any key" thing), is,  I think, available since since basically "forever".

Answer (score 71):

Try:

```
rmdir /S your_directory
```

or:

```
rmdir /S /Q your_directory
```

to skip confirmation messages.

Comment: I already tried these options but as I wrote `del` and `rmdir` doesn't ask anything, they just send out some lines like the one in the description.

Comment: `rmdir /s` will delete anything that's possible to delete. You may have files that are locked by a program, read-only files or files that you need administrative access to delete. There isn't a single command that would take care of all those situations for you

Comment: If you still get error messages, try with PowerShell: the cmdlet Remove-Item it's a bit powerful than rmdir.

Comment: rmdir /s does *not* delete files; it removes directories that have no files in them.

Comment: rmdir /S <directory> Is deleting directory and subfolers and directories. It also asks Are you sure. On Windows 10. Thanks

Comment: @r_alex_hall RMDIR /s does indeed delete files in directories. But DEL /s will delete only the files and keep the directories, which is why RMDIR is the better option

Answer (score 12):

You may have some readonly files, you can use the del /F option to get rid of them using

```
     del /S /F your_directory
     rmdir your_directory
```

You could also have some hidden files and if you are really sure you want to delete them, then you can do this using

```
     del /S /F /AH your_directory
     rmdir your_directory
```

If this still fails, then either you do not have permission to delete some files, or some of the files are still in use.

Comment: This should be the correct answer!

Answer (score 5):

I believe there's a bug in Windows 7 (and perhaps other versions) which sometimes causes this symptom; or it might be a bug in third-party software.  (Do you have Symantec Endpoint Protection installed by any chance?)

Anyway, I've run across it fairly often.  In most cases, the problem can be worked around by running `rd /s /q` two or three times in a row.

If this is in a batch file, you can do something like this:

```
rd /s /q foo
if exist foo rd /s /q foo
if exist foo rd /s /q foo
if exist foo echo Help! & pause
```

Comment: Agreed. Using rd /s foo - that's without the /q silent option -  will delete all the sub folders for you, but you have to answer Y to the prompt, so requires batch files to be attended. Less than ideal I know.

Answer (score 3):

Use `del` on the files inside, then `rmdir` to remove the folder.

To use the `rmdir` method to remove all the files as well, use the `/S` switch *before* the directory name, and `/Q` to suppress prompting for deleting. This is the best way to do it, as you don't miss any files whatsoever. Be careful using the /Q switch though, as it will not warn you of System or Hidden file attributes

Answer (score 2):

If you use [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) you can use the [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) dependency like this:

**run install:** `npm install rimraf -g`

**delete folder:** `rimraf SourceFolder`

This helped me when getting the error:

> the source file names are larger than is supported by the file system

Comment: Your are using npm? common pc users don't know about node js and I don't think they usually install it, mostly developers do.
Good suggestion but simple "rmdir" command is good
https://developingdaily.com/article/technology/basic-cmd-commands-which-windows-user-must-know/129

Comment: @user3559462 yeah you’re probably right. It’s more of just a suggestion if none of the above work for someone.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use it like this:

```
msg*your file is going to delete 
pause
del/s /q "C:\Users\Rd\Desktop\New folder (2)\" 
rmdir /s /q "C:\Users\Rd\Desktop\New folder (2)\"
mkdir "C:\Users\Rd\Desktop\New folder (2)"
```

Comment: Welcome to SU! Why I downvoted? 1) Poor formatting 2) Provides the same essential solution as which was already posted several years ago (always read the posted solutions before posting a new one!) 3) Is not made fit for the question (your solution recreates the deleted folder, which was not asked for).

Comment: I don't think del/s /q was provided anybody else; infact this is the only solution worked for me on command prompt. Providing additional mkdir is not a fault, I suppose. Poor formatting is what one sees. Thanks @Subham

Answer (score 0):

Folder older versions of Windows (DOS, Windows 95/98/ME), `DELTREE` is the equivalent to `RM` or `RMDIR`. I use `DELTREE` on my Windows 7 workstation in batch files just fine though.

```
Deletes a directory and all the subdirectories and files in it.

To delete one or more files and directories:
DELTREE [/Y] [drive:]path [[drive:]path[...]]

  /Y              Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to delete
                  the subdirectory.
  [drive:]path    Specifies the name of the directory you want to delete.

Note: Use DELTREE cautiously. Every file and subdirectory within the
specified directory will be deleted.
```