# How to delete from disk an "app" that windows 10 didn't properly finish installing

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions

So I recently upgraded to windows 10, I had enough space and wanted to try Killer Instinct. When it was nearly complete, my pc shut down. I thought nothing of it and went to bed. Today when I restarted and got into the Windows Store the menu was offering me a kind of "retry" option that wasn't working. I clicked and it was doing nothing. So I cancelled.

I tried to install so it would keep from where it was and I am offered to install from 0, but I have 44GB of data already. So windows does not recognize the "app", the store doesn't either, but I already have that space ocuppied.

To make everything better, I can not delete this folders. I tried manually and it asks for admin permissions. I try to give myself said permissions and fail.

[I try to follow this](https://superuser.com/questions/537757/completely-delete-a-folder-in-windows-using-command-line) and neither option, del or rmdir, work. First one does nothing and the second one tells me `access denied` for every subfolder.

How should I proceed? I have an SSD and 45GB of "dead" data is too much.

Sorry for my broken english I am kind of tired.

Comment: I would just take ownership of the data folder, delete the folder, then reinstall the application

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that concept. I was trying to delete as what I understood was the equivalent of sudo in windows, but this seems like a great idea, I'll try it asap, thanks!